# Casting Object From Class To Fit Generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a Map that receives a `Class<? extends EntityBase>` and gives a `GenericRenderer<? extends EntityBase>`. Inside the `GenericRenderer<? extends EntityBase>`, there's a method called `draw` that takes a `SpriteBatch` and an object that `extends EntityBase` (since the GenericRenderer is holding `<? extends EntityBase>` as the generic).

I'm using the map to hold the renderers for all of my entities, but when I call the `draw` method, Eclipse shows this error:

> The method draw(SpriteBatch, capture#3-of ? extends EntityBase) in the type GenericRenderer is not applicable for the arguments (SpriteBatch, capture#4-of ? extends EntityBase)

Here is the code I use to iterate through my entities, cast them to EntityBase, grab their renderer, and run them through it:

```
for(Entity entity : gameStage.getEntityEngine().getEntities()) {
    if(entity instanceof EntityBase) {
         EntityBase entityBase = (EntityBase) entity;

         GenericRenderer<? extends EntityBase> renderer = 
                 Betley.instance.renderer.getRenderer(entityBase.getClass());

         renderer.draw(batch, entityBase.getClass().cast(entityBase));
    }
}
```

Comment: May you please provide the `draw` method implementation.

Comment: This seems like quite a lot of unnecessary casting and reflection. Why doesn't `EntityBase` have a `draw(Batch)` method on it?

Comment: public abstract void draw(SpriteBatch batch, T object);

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm trying to keep server-side objects separate from client-side processes as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `? extends EntityBase` means that it might be restricted to a subtype, but you don't know what subtype.  That means the compiler can't be sure that the object you're passing is actually of the correct type.

Imagine that you have a pair of classes named `Foo` and `Bar` that both extend `EntityBase`.  If your `renderer` variable is a `GenericRenderer<? extends EntityBase>`, that means the object it refers to could be a `GenericRenderer<Foo>`, or it could be a `GenericRenderer<Bar>`.  The compiler doesn't know which, and it could vary from entity to entity.

So when you call `draw`, you've cast your `entityBase` reference to a specific type like `Foo` or `Bar`, but the compiler can't determine that it's the *right* class.  You might be trying to pass a `Foo` to a renderer that's actually a `Renderer<Bar>`, or vice versa.  That's why you get the error.  `? extends EntityBase` doesn't mean "accepts any subclass of `EntityBase`", it means "might be restricted to a *single* subclass that we don't know".

I suspect your basic design isn't really compatible with how Java's generics work: if you have a `Map` whose values are `GenericRenderer<? extends EntityBase>`, that means you plan to have some values that are `GenericRenderer<Foo>`, some that are `GenericRenderer<Bar>`, and so on.  But there's no information available *at compile time* about which type of entity each renderer needs, so the compiler can't check that you're passing the correct type of entity to each renderer.

You might need to change your map's value type to `GenericRenderer<EntityBase>` and put a cast in each renderer's `draw` method to check (at runtime) that the correct type of entity was passed.  Alternatively, come up with a design that doesn't involve mixing different types of renderers in a single collection.

Comment: As an addendum: if you have the option to use Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library, its [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) might be helpful for this.  You'd need to define subclasses like `FooRenderer` and `BarRenderer`, which extend `GenericRenderer<Foo>` and `GenericRenderer<Bar>` respectively, so that each kind of renderer (not entity) has its own `Class` object to use as a map key.

Comment: But you'd still need a way to look up the renderer `Class` object from the entity `Class` that it renders, and it can be tricky to do that in a type-safe way.